# Integrate BoneCP and EclipseLink with LOCAL_RESOURCE transaction-type

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, connection-pooling, persistence.xml, bonecp

I am setting up a minimal working example where I use EclipseLink in a Java EE (JSF) project. My example works perfectly with the following configuration and code:

`persistence.xml`

```xml
<persistence
    version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
>
    <persistence-unit name="issat_PU_Local" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>pro.entity.Utilisateur</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/issat" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="java" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="JaVa" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Since I don't want to use JTA I am using `RESOURCE_LOCAL` as transaction type and perfectly leaving with "manually" handling transaction inside my DAO.

I now want to use BoneCP connection pool with my example.
How should I precisely modify my `persistence.xml` to do that? I found many configuration examples in the internet using also Hibernate, but I want to stay with EclipseLink.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't do it with bonecp, but I could get a pool connection with C3PO. 
I followed this link : http://javabeginnerstutorial.com/hibernate/connection-pooling-with-hibernate-4/

I copied the dependency and the properties but, instead of `<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>` put the value in the tag like this`<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="1"/>`, otherwise I got an error.

Finally mi persitence.xml look this way:
[image]